How to reorder MongoDB array using Prisma and NextJS
I have this data in mongodb
{
  items: [
    {
      id: '6614005475802af9ae05b6b2',
      title: 'title',
      createdAt: '2024-04-08T14:33:56.734Z',

    },
    {
      id: '6613fda792ffb86a14d266ea',
      title: 'testing',
      createdAt: '2024-04-08T14:22:30.880Z',
    },
    {
      id: '6613fe3675802af9ae05b6a2',
      title: 'cool stuff',
      createdAt: '2024-04-08T14:24:54.580Z',
    }
  ]
}

How can I reorder the positions of the items, using prisma? I couldn't create a "position" field, because seems like MongoDB doesn't allow auto increment from 0/1.

You could be looking for $sortArray. On the other hand, if you are frequently working on the items level, it might be better to store them as individual documents, rather than array entries.

Well, I am working with items frequently, but only to update their positions and titles. Also, I will be having thousands of items, so creating individual docs isn’t the ideal thing to do.

Not sure what you mean by "creating individual docs isn't the ideal thing to do". You could be potentially benefited from an index if you storing the items entries as individual documents like this. And it is just equally easy to recompute the position with $setWindowFields like this

Oh, I see, I thought of something else lol. Yeah, I might try this to see how is going on, thanks.

Wrt

I couldn't create a "position" field, because seems like MongoDB doesn't allow auto increment from 0/1.

If you want to add a "position" field, then use this update query:
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "items": {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              { "position": { $indexOfArray: ["$items", "$$item"] } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)

Mongo Playground
Note:

Use updateMany with this; I'm using update with {multi: true} only for Mongo playground. Also, you may not need the pipeline array syntax [] since it's only one $set step. But it doesn't work on playground without it.


Well, that’s interesting, but I am using prisma for database. I need to auto add the position, because i will be adding tons of items, and i need them updated instantly.

Then 1) Add position to your model after running the update query above. And 2) When you do a $push update (I presume some equivalent in Prisma), then use a position: { $size: "$items" } which will be the current size of the array and the value will be equal to the index of the new object being added to it. However, that only works when adding one item to the array at a time and not multiple. PS. Workaround for that is size from above + newItemIdx when you want to add multiple items.

I would also like to highlight the elegance of the script in the answer. In case your new documents with position are out of sync, say you removed some of the middle entries, you can always rerun the script to reorder the entries.

Wrt

MongoDB doesn't allow auto increment from 0/1.

The $inc update operator does let you increment a given field. However, what you're trying to do is use incremented value for a field in another object; which $inc does not do.
My previous answer relates to adding the position field to all objects in items in all your documents.
Regardless of how you create the positions data, here's how you could insert a new object in items with the correct position value:
Assuming the data now looks like this, with the position field already created:
{
  "_id": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2024-04-08T14:33:56.734Z",
      "id": "6614005475802af9ae05b6b2",
      "position": 0,
      "title": "title"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2024-04-08T14:22:30.880Z",
      "id": "6613fda792ffb86a14d266ea",
      "position": 1,
      "title": "testing"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2024-04-08T14:24:54.580Z",
      "id": "6613fe3675802af9ae05b6a2",
      "position": 2,
      "title": "cool stuff"
    }
  ]
}

This update query will add a new object to the items array and position is auto-calculated from the size of items:
db.collection.update({ _id: 1 },
[
  {
    $set: {
      "items": {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$items",
          [
            {
              "id": "new ID here",
              "createdAt": "2024-04-09T01:23:45.678Z",
              "title": "more cool stuff",
              "position": { $size: "$items" }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

The new object added to items looks like this, note that position is 3:
{
  "createdAt": "2024-04-09T01:23:45.678Z",
  "id": "new ID here",
  "position": 3,
  "title": "more cool stuff"
}

Mongo Playground
Notes:
1. In both queries (this one and my other answer), the position is a 0-based index. If you want to start from 1 instead of 0, then use { $add: [..., 1] } in both places where the value is set. So for this query, you would do:
"position": { $add: [{ $size: "$items" }, 1] }

2. If you expect missing objects, like after deleting the second item, but want to maintain an always increasing position or one-larger-than-last, then use the $max operator and add 1:
"position": { $add: [{ $max: "$items.position" }, 1] }

Mongo Playground. However, in this case, you're better off running the update from my previous answer, so that all position values are sequential & increasing.
